# newKieSession returns null on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, drools

I'm using Intellij ultimate maven project (not a drools project).

I'm trying to run the rules from within the code of the project.

How can I let the session know which rule files apply to it?

I created a single rule file under the same package.

The following code returns null:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("log-perm-session");
```

If I use kContainer.newKieSession() with no name, it throws an exception that there's no default rule file.

I want it to use a specific rule file.

Comment: Do you have a `kmodule.xml` in your classpath? Where? What's its content? Where do you have your drl files?

Comment: No I don't have a kmodule.xml file anywhere. I saw that this file is created automatically in a Drools project. But I want to use it in a regular InteliJ java project. So what should it contain? And how do I add it to the class path then? My drl files are part of the InteliJ java project. I put them in a resources folder.

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that in Intellij kmodule.xml doesn't exist even in a drools project. Only in eclipse I see that it was created.